# TradingView Strategy Tester Run-Up and Drawdown formula

Tags: pine-script

How does TradingView calculate their `Run-Up` and `Drawdown` in the Strategy Tester? More specifically, I'm looking for the formula, because I read the article below but I don't get the formula part.

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000561856-how-are-strategy-tester-report-values-calculated-and-what-do-they-mean/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Run-up` is the maximum theoretical percentage gain, calculated from the price where you entered the trade, to the highest price the stock has reached during the trade.
That price point would have gotten you the greatest percentage gain if you had closed the trade there.

`Drawdown` is the maximum theoretical percentage loss, calculated from the price where you entered the trade, to the lowest price the stock has reached during the trade.
That price point would have gotten you the greatest percentage loss if you had closed the trade there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm trying to process it. `during the trade`, does that include all candles from the buy order to the sell order or just the candle where we bought?

Comment: I think I got the drawdown `quantity * (lowestValueDuringTrade - buyPrice)`. At least it prints correctly. Still trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with the run-up. Isn't it the same but instead of lowestValueDuringTrade using the highest value including the `High` tails?

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawdown = Lowest Value During Trade / (Entry Price x Quantity) x 100
```

---

```
Run-up = Highest Value During Trade / (Entry Price x Quantity) x 100
```